Mark question as duplicate / cross-post from other SE site
Some users originally ask a question on Cross-Validated and as they get no answer there, the same question is cross-posted here. I would like to flag the cross-post here as a duplicate / cross-post from Cross-Validate (or any other SE site), but i receive the warning

The duplicate question must exist on Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange.

This makes sense, as i think a duplicate to be a slightly different question (from another user) on the site here.
How should we flag actual cross-posts on QF of the same user from other sites correctly?

I don't think there is a great way but you can try flagging. Here or there if you think it might fit better on this site. In that case I'd rather not take action on this site. It can help to leave a comment so that potential responders don't do double work.

So you suggest to flag the question on the site where it does fit less? I think this is appropriate as long as the cross-posted question is not answered yet (as the answer might fit for the asking user), but impairs the uninformed answering user in his effort when the question is probably deleted. Is it common on other sites as well, that duplicates can be flagged only within each SE site? Personally i would favor to flag duplicates across the SE universe (and not only the "this question belongs to another site").

As far as I'm aware cross-site duplicate marking doesn't work anywhere. You can flag it everywhere but if it fits well on this site I would not necessarily take action. For me duplicates themselves are not the problem, the problem is people wasting their efforts on answering a question that has been answered elsewhere or not finding an answer because the question is spread all over the internet.
